# how to stub sinon for aws4 sign request

Tags: aws-sdk-nodejs, sinon-chai

I am new to sinon and aws. I need to write a test case for the following code snip. I am unable to locate how to stub for aws4.sign. pls help

```
function signRequest(Parameter, creds, body) {
    console.log("***********  signRequest  *********************");
    var hostname = Parameter.Value.split('//', 2)[1].split('/', 2)[0];
    let request = {
        service: 'execute-api',
        region: REGION,
        host: hostname,
        method: 'POST',
        url: `${Parameter.Value}/api`,
        path: '/api',
        data: body, // object describing the mappedbody
        body: body,
        headers: {
            'content-type': 'application/json'
        }
    };
    var signedRequest = aws4.sign(request, creds);
    console.log("signRequest-->signedRequest: " + signedRequest)
    return signedRequest;
}
```

Comment: You do not need to stub aws4.sign, instead you can pass hard coded parameter values to it and it will return signedRequest object.